# How to go back to previous screen after a timeout request?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I'm trying to set up the network session creator to go back to the previous screen if the timeout request runs out.  As of now I'm not completely sure where or how to execute it. Here is the code:

```
  lazy var configuration: URLSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

  lazy var session: URLSession = URLSession(configuration: self.configuration)

 typealias JSONData = ((Data) -> Void)

  func getJSONData(type: String, urlExtension: String, completion: @escaping JSONData) {

    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5

    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"\(baseURL)\(type)/\(urlExtension)?api_key=\(apiKey)")! )

    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

      if error == nil {
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
          switch (httpResponse.statusCode) {
          case 200:
            if let data = data {
              completion(data)
            }
          default:
            print(httpResponse.statusCode)
          }
        }
      } else {
        print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
      }
    })
    dataTask.resume()
  }
```

Comment: Are you using UINavigationController?

Comment: I am using a  UINavigationController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 lazy var configuration: URLSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

  lazy var session: URLSession = URLSession(configuration: self.configuration)

 typealias JSONData = ((Data) -> Void)

  func getJSONData(type: String, urlExtension: String, onSucceed : @escaping JSONData ,  onFailure: @escaping (_ error:NSError)-> Void ) {

    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5

    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"\(baseURL)\(type)/\(urlExtension)?api_key=\(apiKey)")! )

    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

      if error == nil {
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
          switch (httpResponse.statusCode) {
          case 200:
            if let data = data {
              onSucceed(data)
            }
          default:
            print(httpResponse.statusCode)
          }
        }
      } else {
        onFailure(error! as NSError)
      }
    })
    dataTask.resume()
  }
```

In the View Controller where you call this method I would use it like this.

```
NetworkManager.getJSONData(type: "", urlExtension: "",onSucceed {
   //doSmth
}, on Failure{(error) in 
   //show Error
// if it is pushed
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) 

// or if its presented 
// self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: This request is made inside a singleton but is accessed by the viewcontrollers

Comment: I edited my answer , I added 2 closures : one if the request succeeds and the other one if it fails. Depending on the case you can manage them both.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. this is working for me

```
_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

this will pop the top most `UIViewController` from the `UINavigationController` stack, as a result your previous screen will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you used a show segue to get to your current VC you can use:

```
_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

If you used a modal segue you would use:

```
_ = self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true)
```